# Swipe up/down on window top to maximize/resize to default size

Tags: macos, window-manager, multi-touch, high-sierra

I upgraded my Mac's OS from macOS Sierra to macOS High Sierra today and found one feature disappeared: I used to swipe up on top empty area of a window to maximize the window to "fill" the full screen (not the natural full screen, ie, a new *desktop space*, just making the window as large as possible in the same space); also, by swiping down when the mouse position is on the window top I could resize the window to default size, in the center of the screen.

I can't remember if it is a feature enabled by a util app (like *Hyperdock*) or can be configured in `System Preferences`. I googled around but cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: I find the app! It is [HyperDock](https://bahoom.com/hyperdock). There is a feature in the *window management*: *Scroll a window's title to snap & change space* and that's it!**

---

An alternative way is using [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/): [image]
I set `Command` as the `modifier key` and touch gestures same as the question description. As *Better Touch Tool* doesn't seem to have the option like "triggering the gesture when the cursor touches the empty spot of the window", it will conflict with the default scrolling up and down easily if you don't add a modifier key...